# jQuery animate() doesn't work in Firefox or Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, firefox, webkit, jquery-animate, css-position

I'm working on having three boxes that animate and display text when clicked.  When one is clicked, the others move down to allow for space to display the text.  When the middle is clicked, the other two move down but the clicked one also moves to the left side.

My problem is that while it works fine in Webkit browsers, in Firefox and Internet Explorer the boxes don't animate down and out of the way when the text appears.  It seems as though I've done something that's dependent on the way Webkit works, but as far as I can tell my code is pretty standard.

Edit: here is a JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/CaptainSpectacular/zLnDm/10/, however for some reason it does not recreate the problem that I'm actually having on my site.

Here is my jQuery function:

```
function selectBox($box) {

    switch($box) {
    case 'brand':
            $('.brand-identity').animate({top : 0}, 300)
                .animate({left : 40}, 300)
            $('.web').animate({top : 270, left : 340}, 300);
            $('.print-design').animate({top : 270, left : 640}, 300);
            toggleText('brand');
            break;
        case 'web':
            $('.web').animate({top : '0px'}, 300).animate({left : '40px'}, 300);
            $('.brand-identity').animate({top : '270px'}, 300)
                .animate({left : '40px'}, 300);
            $('.print-design').animate({top : '270px' }, 300)
                .animate({left : '640px'}, 300);
            toggleText('web');
            break;
        case 'print':
            $('.web').animate({left : '340px'}, 300)
                .animate({top : '270px'}, 300);
            $('.brand-identity').animate({top :'270px'}, 300)
                .animate({left : '40px'}, 300);
            $('.print-design').animate({top : '0px'}, 300)
                .animate({left : '640px'}, 300);
            toggleText('print');
            break;
    }
}
```

(toggleText simply decides which text div to show/hide based on the input string)

And the html that it is supposed to affect:

```
<div class="services-box-container">
    <div class="services-box brand-identity">
        <img class="brand-color"src="/images/services/brand-icon-color.png">
        <p>brand<br/>identity</p>
    </div>

    <div class="brand-text">
        <p>brand text</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="services-box-container">
    <div class="services-box web">
        <img class="web-color"src="/images/services/web-icon-color.png">
        <p>web</p>
    </div>

<div class="web-text">
    <p>Web Text</p>
</div>                      
</div>

<div class="services-box-container">
    <div class="services-box print-design">
        <img class="print-color"src="/images/services/print-icon-color.png">
        <p>print<br/>design</p>
    </div>

    <div class="print-text">
        <p>print text</p>                   
    </div>                      
</div>
```

And finally the css for those boxes:

```
.services-box {
    top: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 230px;
    height: 230px;
}
.brand-identity {
    top: 0;
    left: 40px;
}
.web {
    top: 0;
    left: 340px;
}
.print-design {
    top: 0;
    left: 640px;
 }
```

Comment: You have a function but I see nothing that calls it.

Comment: Can you create a http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: function selectBox($box) is called by click events attached to each box.  For instance, when the Web box is clicked it calls selectBox('web');  I know that these click events are working because no matter what, the text is always displayed correctly, and the function for that is only called from within selectBox().

I will work on creating a jsfiddle.

Comment: I added the jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/CaptainSpectacular/zLnDm/10/) however it does not recreate my problem.  This leads me to believe that it might be an issue with the containing div around that bit of code.

Comment: @CaptainSpectacular your Fiddle demo works fine in IE and FF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with an if statement which I left out of the jsfiddle in order to simplify it.  This interaction was only meant to take place in a full screen window on a desktop, so inside each click event handler was:

```
if(document.width > 960){
    //Event handling
}
```

This does not work because Firefox and IE return "undefined" for that attribute.

I tried changing it to screen.width, but that seems to return the width of my monitor, and window.width gave the same result as document.width.  The solution was to use the actual jQuery $(window).width(), that returns the same results for all the browsers.